# in BeautifulSoup how to split the soup by certain words?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 to **scrape** a document which has a format like this, and only want all the *a* tag elements above text2. How can I do so?

```
<h1>text1</h1>
<a href="link">link</a>

<h1>text2</h1>
<a href="link"></a>
```

If I turn soup into string and split, not sure I can turn it back to soup and I need to use the `soup.find_all('a')` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `soup.find_all_previous()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<h1>text1</h1>
<a href="link">link</a>

<h1>text2</h1>
<a href="link"></a>""", "html.parser")

print(soup.find("h1", text="text2").find_all_previous())
```

---

```
[<a href="link">link</a>, <h1>text1</h1>]
```